# How to access a different part of the data while using pipe

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Let say I have the following data

```
AgentID Position FriendID
1 1 2
2 4 1
3 10 2
```

What I want to do is something like following

```
d[, .SD , by=AgentID] %>%
(for each of the subsets - disected according to AgentID, called the current AgentID -, 
select the part of `d` where the FriendID is the current AgentID. )
(calculate the distance between Friend's position and current Agent's position)
```

How can I do that?

Do note that, the above is just a toy example to just to understand the concept

**Edit:**

The expected output would be like

```
AgentID Position FriendID distanceToFriend
1 1 2 3
2 4 1 3
3 10 2 6
```

Comment: Btw, in your toy example, `AgentID` is never equal to `FriendID`. So in this specific case you would not get a useful result.

Comment: 1's friend is 2. 2's friend is 1. 3's friend 2. I can't understand what you mean

Comment: You are saying `select the part of d where the AgentID == FriendID of the current AgentID`. @bird is saying that none of the rows satisfy `AgentID == FriendID`. Your data may be clear to you, but it is not really clear to others (myself included).

Comment: @slamballais see my edit please

Comment: `df %>% mutate(dist = abs(Position - Position[match(FriendID, df$AgentID)]))`

Comment: OR `DT[, dist := abs(Position - Position[match(FriendID, DT$AgentID)])][]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below make a self join with `data.table` from `d` on itself, linking `AgentID` with `FriendID` via the `on = .(AgentID = FriendID)` argument.
You might have a look at this [tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html) to understand better the join logic.
In this kind of `LHS[RHS,...]` join, if variables have the same name on both sides (which is obviously the case on a self join), you can choose which side to use with the `x.` prefix (not used here) for `LHS` and `i.` prefix for `RHS`.
`x.` and `i.` refers to general `data.table` `X[i,j,by]` syntax.

```
d[d,.(AgentID, 
      Position = i.Position,
      FriendID = i.FriendID,
      distance = abs(Position-i.Position))
   ,on = .(AgentID = FriendID)]

#   AgentID Position FriendID distance
#1:       1        1        2        3
#2:       2        4        1        3
#3:       3       10        2        6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can perform a self-join :

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df, df, by = c('AgentID' = 'FriendID')) %>%
  transmute(FriendID = AgentID, 
            AgentID = AgentID.y,
            distanceToFriend = abs(Position.x - Position.y)) %>%
  arrange(AgentID)

#  FriendID AgentID distanceToFriend
#1        2       1                3
#2        1       2                3
#3        2       3                6
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. A quick question though: you never defined `Position.y`, so where doesn't that come from?

Comment: that comes when we merge the data. Since both the data in merge have the same column names, to differentiate between them `.x` and `y` is added to them as suffix. You can check output of `inner_join(df, df, by = c('AgentID' = 'FriendID'))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
d$distanceToFriend <- abs(d$Position - d$Position[match(d$FriendID, d$AgentID)])
```

Comment: @Our ok.  can you update your post with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` option

```
d[
  ,
  distanceToFriend := .SD[
    ,
    abs(diff(d[, Position][unlist(.(AgentID, FriendID))]))
  ],
  AgentID
][]
```

gives

```
   AgentID Position FriendID distanceToFriend
1:       1        1        2                3
2:       2        4        1                3
3:       3       10        2                6
```